# IDEA Intellij. Parameter annotation not inherited

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, annotations

I upgraded IntelliJ a couple of days ago and the current version is 2017.2

When I tried implementing methods with annotated parameter by intention, the generated code does not include the annotations.

For example:

Given a method in the interface.

```
void test(@TestAnnotation(name = "arg1") String arg1, @TestAnnotation2(name = "arg2") String arg2);
```

The generated code will be

```
void test(String arg1, String arg2);
```

I do remember it will bring annotations from super class/interface before. 
I also find this checked in settings.

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ settings that show the option "Annotate overriding methods and their parameters" is checked]

Is there anything wrong with my IDEA or the settings or is it a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the annotations to copy here:

[image: copy annotations]

In previous versions IntelliJ IDEA copied all the annotations, but a lot of user complained since not all of them should be copied. Well known annotations are still copied automatically, but the custom ones have to be configured manually.